# <use> within <svg> not finding closest <div> in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, svg, shadow-dom

I have a structure set up like so:

```
<div class="linkedItem" data-yt="youtubelink">
  <svg><use></svg>
  <div>youtube link</div>
</div>
```

In jQuery, I've assigned a click event on the wrapper `<div>`:

```
$("div.linkedItem").on("click",launchYouTube);

function launchYouTube(e){
    var _src = $(e.target).closest(".linkedItem").data("yt"));
};
```

In the event handler, I get a value for `_src` in Chrome, but in IE11 it's **undefined**. It seems that the `<use>` in IE11 doesn't know what its parent is, and therefore can't find the closest `div.linkedItem`.

I saw an article about [svg gotchas](https://css-tricks.com/gotchas-on-getting-svg-into-production/), and the closest I can think is #4 (jQuery throws error), but I don't think that's it for some reason.  Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For each SVGUseElement, the SVG DOM maintains a shadow tree (the "instance tree") of objects of type SVGElementInstance. The SVGUseElement has an instanceRoot property that points to the SVGElementInstance at the root of the shadow tree.  The SVGElementInstance has a a correspondingUseElement property that points back to the SVGUseElement. These two properties allow you to jump between the main DOM tree and the shadow tree.

I tested your example in both Internet Explorer and Chrome. In Chrome, the 'click' event is passed the SVGUseElement which jQuery then uses to walk up the main DOM tree to find the desired 'div' element. In Internet Exploer, the 'click' event is passed the SVGElementInstance which jQuery then uses to walk up the shadow tree. Since the shadow tree is not part of the main DOM tree, jQuery never finds the desired 'div' element.

You could work around this issue by checking the target. If target is a SVGElementInstance then pass target.correspondingUseElement to jQuery else pass target to jQuery. You could check for SVGELementInstance by testing for correspondingUseElement property or by testing toString() equals "[object SVGElementInstance]".

For example, you could replace...

```
function launchYouTube(e){
    var _src = $(e.target).closest(".linkedItem").data("yt"));
};
```

with...

```
function launchYouTube(e){
    var target = e.target;
    if (target.correspondingUseElement) {
        target = target.correspondingUseElement;
    }
    var _src = $(target).closest(".linkedItem").data("yt");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(_src));
};
```

or....

```
function launchYouTube(e){
    var target = e.target;
    if (target.toString() === "[object SVGElementInstance]") {
        target = target.correspondingUseElement;
    }
    var _src = $(target).closest(".linkedItem").data("yt");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(_src));
};
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me solve an issue in a D&D lib I use :) https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/pull/356/files